# Why can't I create lists within a list using loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have this code (For the left wall of roomMap):

```
roomMap = []
ones = [1] * 50
for i in ones:
    roomMap = roomMap + [[i]]
    roomMap.append("\n")
print(len(roomMap))
print(roomMap)
```

It is supposed to print `50` then `[1]` on 50 lines, but it prints `100` then repeats `[1], '\n'` 50 times.
Why is this happenning?

Comment: You created `[[1], '\n', [1], '\n' ....]`, with 50 times the pair `[1], "\n"`, so what is surprising here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
roomMap = [1] * 50 # Here, the list is filled with 1
print(len(roomMap))
for i in roomMap:
    print(i)
```

print() already go to next line.
This print :

```
50
1
1
1
1 #etc..
```

If you want a list of lists, just add brackets

```
roomMap = [[1]] * 50 #Here, the list is filled with [1]
print(len(roomMap))
for i in roomMap:
    print(i)
```

This print

```
50
[1]
[1]
[1] #etc..
```

Comment: I obviously deleted " for i in ones: roomMap.append(i) " cause it just copy the [[1]]*50 ...

Answer (score 0):

It prints 100 and repeats [1], '\n' 50 times because you append the "\n" to the roomMap.

What you did is appending both [1] and "\n" into the list "roomMap". So, for every single iteration, you are pushing 2 elements ([1] and "\n") to the list. A list is not a string, so you do not need to append the whitespace character.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. Do you know a way to add the newline?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
roomMap = []
ones = [1] * 50
for i in ones:
    roomMap = roomMap + [[i]]
print(len(roomMap))
for i in roomMap:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
roommap=[]
a=[[1]]*50
for i in a:
    roommap.append(i)
print(len(a))
print(*roommap,sep='\n')
```